# Category.php doesn't work after I remove 'category' from the permalink Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

II try to remove 'category' from the permalink (Category Base name to **.** and link to **%category%/%postname%**)
But after that the page domain.com/news doesn't work (I see the template of index.php)
before it domain.com/category/news worked
domain.com/news/name-news works in both cases

why I got the error and how can I fix it?

I have **category.php** where I have code for content of domain.com/category/news for example

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make sure that you have flushed the rewrite rules. You can do this either by going to settings->permalinks, and saving, or by putting in the following into an action. Don't keep running it on each load though, as it has performance issues

```
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules

If that doesn't work, please show how you are setting the permalink